# how to hide/use encrypted username and password of spring rabbitMQ XML configuration

Tags: spring-amqp

Is there a way to hide/encrypt user/password of connection factory in spring rabbitMQ configuration (outside annotation based programs) , like to use XML configuration but ths is a bottleneck

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box, but you can subclass the `CachingConnectionFactory` and override `setUsername()` and `setPassword()`.

```
@Override
public void setUsername(String username) {
    super.setUsername(decrypt(username));
}

@Override
public void setPassword(String password) {
    super.setPassword(decrypt(password));
}

private String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    ...
}
```

And then

```
<bean id="connectionFactory" class="com.foo.MyFactorySubclass">
    <property name="username" value="jdj87878fdghfjdfg" />
    <property name="password" value="jfkjdhjs76867nn_sdnasj" />
    ...
</bean>
```